# Can we access orkut using RSS?

Tags: rss

Is it possible to access orkut (features of orkut such as scraps, friend find, etc.) through RSS?
We can access facebook using RSS.
Does orkut provides similar facility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. When I tried to do something similar, I had to go with CRAWLING the pages I was interested in: scraps, private messages, birthdays...

Comment: Thanks Pablo for answer.
I was hoping that there will be some API for this. But it seems that there is no way.

Comment: No. Unfortunately, no API. I have been looking for an API for ORKUT for a long time but couldn't find one. Since Orkut is only big in India, Brazil and Paraguay, I guess Google does not care about releasing an API for it...